# How to configure Secor (from pinterest) to partition files by hour of day?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Looking for some insight on how to configure Secor to output fatter files that are partitioned by datetime rather than kafka offset. Something akin to hourly backups of kafka topic streams. Currently, my common.properties file contains these secor configs:

```
secor.generation=1
secor.consumer.threads=7
secor.messages.per.second=10000
secor.offsets.per.partition=10000000
secor.topic_partition.forget.seconds=600
secor.local.log.delete.age.hours=-1
    secor.file.reader.writer.factory=com.pinterest.secor.io.impl.SequenceFileReaderWriterFactory
secor.max.message.size.bytes=100000
```

This file mentions that a partition could describe the date of a message:

[LogFilePath.java](https://github.com/pinterest/secor/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pinterest/secor/common/LogFilePath.java):

> (line 29) Log file path has the following form:   prefix/topic/partition1/.../partitionN/generation_kafkaParition_firstMessageOffset
>
> (line 34) "partition1, ..., partitionN is the list of partition names extracted
> from message content.  *         E.g., the partition may describe the
> message date such as dt=2014-01-01 [...]"

Comment: I noticed in the 
[secor.dev.properties](https://github.com/pinterest/secor/blob/master/src/main/config/secor.dev.properties) there is a max file age property. 
Also `message.timestamp.name=dateTime` must be set to match timestamp key in kafka message.

Comment: Also noting that JsonMessageParser expect the timestamp field to be on the top level (not nested) and in the Unix TS format. If your message format differs, you would need to write your custom Message Parser class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Secor's Readme File](https://github.com/pinterest/secor):
JSON date parser: parser that extracts timestamps from JSON messages and groups the output based on the date, similar to the Thrift parser above. To use this parser, start Secor with properties file `secor.prod.partition.properties` and set `secor.message.parser.class=com.pinterest.secor.parser.JsonMessageParser`. You may override the field used to extract the timestamp by setting the `message.timestamp.name` property.

Comment: Does this only work if you also timestamp all of your messages in the JSON of the message? I am looking for doing this partitioning by the datetime Secor arrives at the message,  perhaps slightly different or possibly the same as the question from OP.

Comment: Yes,  looking at the source the timestamp information is parsed from the JSON content. In your case, you might consider creating a custom class  that extends the JsonMessageParser, creates this timestamp information at runtime and passes it to the JsonMessageParser methods.